# Restarting a clean Windows 10 PRO installation went to Windows 8 Home

Tags: windows, windows-8

Here is my situation:

1. Laptop with Windows 8 Home Edition x64.
2. Upgrades to 8.1 Home Edition.
3. I got a license key for Windows 8.1 Professional Edition using Dreamspark Premium from the university (onthehub...)
4. I got an upgrade to Windows 10 Professional x64 -> I was so happy with Hyper-V for Windows Phone Development (the emulator required it) I was able to join enterprise domains, remote Desktop was very helpful for me, the fancy feature for mount .iso files: amazing!
5. It was fine, something 'critical' happened on the start menu... and other problems without solution... I was thinking: maybe I need to reinstall Windows 10 and get everything fresh.
6. I created the Recovery Drive under Windows 10 Professional Edition.
7. I made a backup for all my files using an external HDD.
8. **I reinstall the Windows 10 Professional and... Greetings from Windows 8 Home Edition -> !!!0.0 WT...?! #FAIL**
9. The Dreamspark Premium from my university is not working anymore (they didn't continue with the program -> this is very sad: The WebStore associated with the address above is currently inactive. Please contact your organization administrator to obtain the current address if one exists.) => there is no key...

The nice part is that my computer recover the speed it has before all my programs... lol

**What do I need to do to solve this -> Recover my Windows 10 Professional Edition**

Is it possible?

Comment: " Regards from Windows 8 Home Edition -> !!!0.0 WT...?! #FAIL" what does this mean?

Comment: it means that my Windows 10 Professional Edition is gone, and I am using the original Os (Windows 8 Home). by the way, I am going to update, the correct word is 'greetings' instead of 'regards'

Comment: Solution: Download Windows 10 .ISO, when ask for a key, provide the Windows 8.1 Professional key.  If you don't have the license you are our luck.  Your problem is because of the embedded key.  If you had asked for us we could have solved your problem for you